# Legally misleading comments about licensing need cleanup

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

I answered a question indirectly related to Oracle Java licensing and someone commented on my answer propounding a legal theory that is 1) wrong, and 2) inappropriate ... given that Stack Overflow is not an appropriate place to ask for or offer legal advice.

I flagged the comments as "no longer required" since I have addressed the minor point in my answer that they related to.  The flags were declined some time ago.

Today I raised a "needs moderator attention" flag, stating:

> "Johannes nitpick (which I corrected) is based on [a] legal theory that has no foundation. Please delete all comments on this question. Stack Overflow should not be seen to be offering BAD legal advice." – Stephen C 4 hours ago   helpful

I also added a comment to say why the theory is without foundation.  (OK, I am not a lawyer.  But I do understand a bit about the GPL and copyright law and how they operate ... having followed [Groklaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groklaw) avidly for a number of years.)

The flag was accepted ... but the comments were not removed.

I can see that I *should have* asked "Please delete all comments on this **answer**".  Sorry.  My mistake.

Could a moderator please take another look at this.  If the comments on my answer can't be removed, I think I need to remove my answer.  Which would be a pity.

The Q&A is [How to get java 11 run-time environment working since there is no more jre 11 for download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111921/how-to-get-java-11-run-time-environment-working-since-there-is-no-more-jre-11-fo/53112096#53112096)

Comment: I haven't looked into all the details of this,  but it seems like you are raising a flag on a comment because you think the comment is *wrong*. This is not a valid reason to ask for a comment to be deleted. Moderators do not police the technical accuracy of comments.

Comment: @CodyGray Then how does one go about getting incorrect and misleading comments removed? We can't downvote or delete vote them, the only thing we can do is post other comments to dispute them creating a discussion that's not immediately relevant to the question/answer.

Comment: You don't, @Erik. There's no facility for disputing comments other than leaving a counter-argument as a comment of your own. If the discussion is *truly* irrelevant to the post on which it is attached, then flagging the comment is a valid choice. Otherwise, don't flag comments just because you disagree with them. Put yourself in the other position: do you want a moderator deleting *your* comments just because some random flagger disagreed with them?

Comment: If there was a critical flaw in an answer, I'd be OK with my comments addressing it getting removed, since I could and should just create my own answer and have the space to properly explain, edit in the future, provide proper quote formatting, etc. Comments are not intended for these kinds of discussions. Once the author of an answer has seen and assessed my criticism, it's no longer needed imo, and since it's the author of the answer flagging comments on his answer it should be honored (meta is an exception because we do allow extended discussion in the comments here, of course).

Comment: You are assuming it's the author of the answer on which you are commenting that flags it, @Erik. I see *tons* of comments getting flagged by people because they disagree with them. Often, they're "possible duplicate" comments. Other times, they're helpful nuggets of advice left by people without the time to write an answer or because the question is incomplete. You're describing a scenario where the comment fits the "no longer needed" flag, not a hypothetical "this comment is wrong" flag. We do not want that flag, that's why it has not been provided.

Comment: @CodyGray In this specific case, I _know_ it's the author of the answer that raised the flag, as it's specified in the question. That's why I was surprised it was rejected. If it was a random flagger, I'd understand rejecting the flag better. Since it's 6 comments, I thought you'd prefer a custom flag, though _irrelevant discussion_ would probably be better than _comments are wrong_ in this case.

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't raise this.  But in this case this is not just "these comments are wrong".  It is "these comments are incorrect legal advice".   That's a lot more harmful than just plain wrong ... or even irrelevant.   Please consider **that**.

Comment: You are suggesting that people see some legal blurb in a comment and then go "Okay, that is the only truth and I will believe it instantly". No, it's not harmful. Just a huge eyesore.

Comment: Yes. I am suggesting that. You could say that people who ask for advice for advice on licenses are naive ... and deserve what they get.  But isn't it better that they don't find bad advice here?

Comment: @ErikA : The common method of getting a comment removed is to reply to it and start a heated discussion about it, planning it carefully so that it attracts even more comments. Plan your replies in a way that they are slightly demeaning, not offensive enough to be deleted on their own, but enough so that it will attract even more comments. Once the comment thread becomes long enough, a moderator will show by and delete the whole thing.  :)  I've seen this strategy masterfully applied by many users, especially at politics.se when they have an ideological disagreement with a certain comment.

Comment: @vsz the way to avoid that happening is to state your point and move on. I takes two to debate. If a comment is in any way demeaning it can be flagged for deletion.

Comment: @YvetteColomb : This means that either I wasn't clear enough, or you didn't get my sarcasm. My point was that there are some people who, when they want a comment removed, start an endlessly long debate with the deliberate purpose of getting the whole debate (including the original comment) deleted.

Comment: @vsz I totally understood and it does happen. Your comment was flagged, so I addressed it with a real life solution to the phenoma you described.

Answer (score 20):

FWIW I deleted the comment thread (as a result of this question), as it became a cyclic debate that was not going to be resolved. It's a shame in a way the question is closed as a duplicate (in fact you dupe hammered it) as the commenter could have written their own answer. As it stands they can post an answer on the target question.

I'm a firm believer that comments are transient. If people want their opinions/expertise noticed, they should be posting answers. Comments can only be upvoted, answers can be up or downvoted. This way it gives the community a fairer way to weigh in on the merit of those opinions.

From the [Help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

> #### When should I comment?
>
> .../...
>
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
>
> ...
>
> #### When shouldn't I comment?
>
> .../...
>
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;

Comment: I have reopened the Question.  I have misgivings though.  If someone did decide to restate the gist of the now deleted comments as an answer, it is difficult to see how they would relevant to the question.

Answer (score 12):

Right, so there are at least *two* thoughts on my mind about this comment chain:

- If a user decides to get their legal advice from the Internet, then there's *really* not much we can do to help save them.  They would have **no one but themselves to blame** if they did.
- It's not been standing policy for comments to be deleted because they're *wrong*; they have to be actively harmful or detrimental to an individual.

If nothing else, it'll give the person who posted that comment one more to delete come Winter Bash time.  I don't think this is something we *need* to involve moderators on.

Comment: Besides, the law SE website is better suited for getting legal advices (though it doesn't count as an official advice from a professional).

Comment: Or another StackExchange site where it would be on-topic: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/